# Query the GC with C# and port 3268

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to query the global catalog and bind to port 3268 with C# in order to get users from the domain AND its children domains, but I get error "domain name format specified is not valid". Here's the sample code I'm using :

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
string path = "LDAP://" + context.ConnectedServer + ":3268/rootDSE";
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(path);
string configNC = searchRoot.Properties["configurationNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
DirectoryEntry configSearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + context.ConnectedServer + ":3268/" + configNC);
DirectorySearcher configSearch = new DirectorySearcher(configSearchRoot);
configSearch.Filter = ("(NETBIOSName=*)");
configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dnsroot");
configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ncname");
configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("NETBIOSName");
SearchResultCollection forestPartitionList = configSearch.FindAll();
//(...)
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the domain controller you are connecting to has Global Catalog role? You can check this by reading [isGlobalCatalogReady](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223256.aspx) property from rootDSE.

Comment: Yes, this property returns TRUE